# Complex numbers ValueError: Attempt to convert a value with an unsupported type to a Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was using tensorflow 1 to do complex-valued neural networks and was Ok.
However I didn't do it on eager mode and now tensorflow 2 is getting on my nerves. Apparently all is keras now so I tried to implement a layer like this:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf


class Linear(layers.Layer):

  def __init__(self, units=32, input_dim=32):
    super(Linear, self).__init__()
    w_init = tf.complex(tf.random_normal_initializer(), tf.random_normal_initializer())
    self.w = tf.Variable(initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_dim, units)),
                         trainable=True, dtype=tf.complex64)

  def call(self, inputs):
    return tf.abs(tf.matmul(inputs, self.w))

x = tf.complex(tf.ones((2, 2)), tf.ones((2, 2)))
linear_layer = Linear(4, 2)
y = linear_layer(x)
print(y)
```

However I get the error:

```
ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops_v2.RandomNormal object at 0x7f64daf8ad90>) with an unsupported type (<class 'tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops_v2.RandomNormal'>) to a Tensor.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `tf.random_normal_initializer()` produces a `tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops_v2.RandomNormal` object, which is not a number, but `tf.complex` expects tensors as inputs.